# Desktop site link from mobile site

Tags: html, mobile, desktop

I am working on a site that has a mobile site: http://www.exchequersolutions.co.uk/m/ I am trying to create a link to the desktop site with out much luck.

When the user clicks on a link I want them to be taken to the desktop site.

The link in the anchor tag is:

```
    <p><a href="http://www.exchequersolutions.co.uk/contractors/cis-self-employed/cis-form/" target="_blank" class="cis_register" >Register Online</a></p>
```

Does anybody know how or even if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible.

Every browser implement a function to save a link on OS FileSystem (drag&drop or file > save as ...).

Comment: I've just seen the nationwide site and they seem to have accomplished it: http://www.nationwide.co.uk/ In the footer there is a link to the mobile site

Comment: Where is the "save" function?

Comment: Im not sure where the save as button is, i just noticed that the desktop site can be linked to from the mobile site

Comment: You can add a site to your home screen on mobile device such as iPhone or iPad

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck in a loop caused by user-agent detection.

It looks like there is device detection on the desktop site that uses the user-agent to identify mobile devices. If you follow a link to the desktop site using a mobile phone, you'll just be sent back to the mobile site.

There are a few different ways you can fix this, but it depends on your site architecture. One way would be to disable the redirect on the desktop site if you include a specific parameter in the query string. Another option would be to set a cookie and use that to disable the redirect.